# Can an outlet be installed in the blank door panel in front of a sink?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

According to the code what does it say about a receptacle outlet installed on a kitchen sink drawer? Can you do it or not? The panel is assumed to be fake. 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's an operable drawer there? From where it's located, I'd expect that to be a dummy panel piece that doesn't open at all...also, is that outlet GFCI protected?

Comment: I'm not sure a fake panel can be considered a permanent installation

Comment: Yes it is fake, thank you for pointing that out! This question is for a group discussion and we are debating whether it should be GFCI protected. It should be GFCI protected, right?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is not a group discussion forum; you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 5):

It's no more wrong than an outlet in any permanent cabinetry.  Which is to say, not.

However, it seems rather useless. Kitchen appliances have cords only 2 feet long.  I do not see how you could make any use of it without draping cords across the sink, the very thing Code seeks to avoid!

As far as Code requirements to have kitchen counter receptacles within 24" of any counter space, this outlet won't meet that requirement brcause its use is impracticable.  If cutting a hole in the counter for a flat-mount receptacle does not appeal, I would use a pendant dropped down from the ceiling.  Pendants are awesome.

As far as GFCI, do you really have to ask?  It is within 6 feet of a sink!  Of course the GFCI doesn't have to be right there; it can be a plain outlet protected by a GFCI somewhere else.

Comment: Might be OK for a vacuum or powered mop, but yea, wouldn't ever use that for a countertop appliance.

Comment: Ergo no reason to install it @JPhi1618 ... I have a hunch this has to do with mandatory kitchen countertop receptacles within 24" of any counter space.  This would not satisfy the requirement.